# Vue property not found

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i am very new to vue.js using in laravel, so i have here is very basic thing i am implementing, this is supposed to be wizard with steps. When i open the page i am keep getting "step" is undefined. I tried googling it and couldnt find any possible solution. Any help would be great.

```
<div class="container  u-space-2-top" id="content">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-between align-items-md-center mb-7">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-7 mb-md-0" v-if="step === 1">
            <h1 class="h3 font-weight-bold">STEP 1</h1>
            <div class="float-right">
                        <a href="javascript:;" 
                           @click.prevent="next()">
                            Next &raquo;
                          </a>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-7 mb-md-0" v-if="this.step === 2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>STEP 2</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

window.Vue = require('vue');
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: function (){
        return {
            step: 1,
            cv: null,
            formErrors: [],
            formSubmitted: false,
            applicant: {
                    first_name: '',
                    last_name: '',
                    email: '',
                    phone: '',
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    },

    methods: {
        prev(){
            this.step--;
        },
        next(){
            this.step++;
        },
        submit(){
            alert("ready to submit");
        }
}
```

Comment: Is the error that `step` is undefined, or that `this.step` is undefined?

Comment: just step, if i set this.step then i get both div hidden

Comment: When you say you keep getting `"step" is undefined`, could you elaborate on what that means? Are you logging it to the console somewhere or is it an error message? If it's an error message could you please quote the exact message including the stack trace. I don't see anything in the code you provided that would cause `step` to be `undefined`.

Comment: i get error in developer tools like this ReferenceError: step is not defined

Comment: So in the browser's console you're seeing `ReferenceError: step is not defined` without any stack trace, filename or line number?

Comment: Are you using the laravel scaffolding for vue? Why are you creating your own instance if laravel provides it?

Comment: i already implemented for another page the same way and it works. course i dont call it step variable there just use it in functions inside js.

Comment: I suspect you've got two Vue instances fighting over the same `<div>`. Try adding `<div id="content">Dummy</div>` and then change your current `<div>` to be `id="content2"`, with `el: '#content2'`. This isn't a solution but it may help to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using laravel the easier way to get setup is the following steps:

edit or create `resources/views/welcome.blade.php` to the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <example-component></example-component>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

edit or create `resources/js/components/ExampleComponent` with the following content:

```
<template>
    <div class="container  u-space-2-top" id="content">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-between align-items-md-center mb-7">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-7 mb-md-0" v-if="step === 1">
                <h1 class="h3 font-weight-bold">STEP 1</h1>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <a href="javascript:;"
                       @click.prevent="next()">
                        Next &raquo;
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-7 mb-md-0" v-if="step === 2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5>STEP 2</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function (){
            return {
                step: 1,
                cv: null,
                formErrors: [],
                formSubmitted: false,
                applicant: {
                    first_name: '',
                    last_name: '',
                    email: '',
                    phone: '',
                }
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        methods: {
            prev(){
                this.step--;
            },
            next(){
                this.step++;
            },
            submit(){
                alert("ready to submit");
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

Run the following command:

```
npm run watch
```

If there isn't a welcome route use the following:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
  return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: some how the functions are also undefined

Comment: Checkout the updated example with click example @adrian

Comment: understood but i cant even see the next button since the whole page throws error on step variable

Comment: You are using this.step in your view, this should be `step`, checkout the example @adrian

Comment: i tried both ways, this.step gives no error and nothing displays and just with step i get undefined error, not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I updated the example to use the laravel approach can you check it out? @adrian

Comment: Let me try @Maartendev.

Comment: it started displaying properly now but i am getting next function undefined. any ideas?

Comment: did you run the `npm run watch` command and run a hard refresh(`ctrl f5` or `cmd shift r`? @adrian

Comment: yes i did that @Maatendev, atleast no step variable error

Comment: Could you try cloning the following repo and testing if it works: https://github.com/MaartenGDev/test-vue-setup @adrian

Comment: That one working @Maartendev, maybe my project i need to refresh since i made some changes based on your project.

Comment: Could you try deleting the `app.js` file in `public/js` loading the page in your browser. Check if it shows 404 and then run `npm run dev`? @adrian

Comment: sure @Maartendev i will try it and let you know

Comment: its working now @Maatendev, i will mark your answer

Comment: Great to hear! Was it just the cache or something else? @adrian

Comment: cache and also spelling mistake method instead of methods

Answer (score 0):

Try to set 'data' as object, not as function:

```
data: {
  step: 1,
  cv: null,
  formErrors: [],
  formSubmitted: false,
  applicant: {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
  }

},
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code in snippet and it works.
It's not the answer, but hope it helps.

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: function (){
        return {
            step: 1,
            cv: null,
            formErrors: [],
            formSubmitted: false,
            applicant: {
                    first_name: '',
                    last_name: '',
                    email: '',
                    phone: '',
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    },

    methods: {
        prev(){
            this.step--;
        },
        next(){
            this.step++;
        },
        submit(){
            alert("ready to submit");
        }
}
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container  u-space-2-top" id="content">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-between align-items-md-center mb-7">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-7 mb-md-0" v-if="step === 1">
            <h1 class="h3 font-weight-bold">STEP 1</h1>
            <div class="float-right">
                        <a href="javascript:;" 
                           @click.prevent="next()">
                            Next &raquo;
                          </a>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-7 mb-md-0" v-if="this.step === 2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>STEP 2</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe the laravel does render properly or something which is hard to figure it out